# Como utilizar o mesmo suplemento .xla em duas máquinas na mesma planilha?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Criei um arquivo com funções em VBA .xla que pode ser configurado como suplemento de excel, porém após utilizar as funções em uma planilha qualquer na minha máquina e enviar a planilha para outra pessoa ela não consegue visualizar o retorno da função fica aquele #NOME, obs: foi configurado o xla na máquina da pessoa que enviei tbm.

```
Sub conectaBD()

    Dim MySQLdrive As String

    If (cn Is Nothing) Then
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    End If

    If Not (cn.State = adStateOpen) Then

        MySQLdrive = Get_Driver()

        With cn
            .ConnectionString = "Driver={" & MySQLdrive & "};Server=" & Server_Name & ";DATABASE=" & DataBase & ";User=" & User_ID & ";Password=" & Password & ";Option=3;"
            .Open
        End With

    End If

End Sub

Function consultaValorPL(cod_Operacao As Integer, data As Date) As Double

    Dim SQLStr As String

    consultaValorPL = 0#

    SQLStr = "CALL listar_pu_por_data('" & Format(data, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "', " & cod_Operacao & ")"

    Call conectaBD

    Set rs = cn.Execute(SQLStr)

    If Not (rs.EOF) Then
        consultaValorPL = rs("pl").Value
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If


End Function

    Function Get_Driver() As String

    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    Dim l_Registry As Object
    Dim l_RegStr As Variant
    Dim l_RegArr As Variant
    Dim l_RegValue As Variant

    Get_Driver = ""
    Set l_Registry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    l_Registry.enumvalues HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers", l_RegStr, l_RegArr

    For Each l_RegValue In l_RegStr
        If InStr(1, l_RegValue, "MySQL ODBC", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Get_Driver = l_RegValue
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set l_Registry = Nothing
End Function
```

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Poste o conteúdo do arquivo.xla para que possamos ajudar com uma possível causa. Ou dê mais detalhes em sua dúvida. Apenas as informações passadas não são suficientes para que alguem possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Szag-Ot as informações ainda não são suficientes?

Comment: a base de dados com a qual seu script se conecta, está acessível da outra máquina tb?

Comment: @Szag-Ot sim, tanto é que quando eu configuro o suplemento a fórmula funcionan maquina da pessoa, o problema é quando eu  entrego uma planilha feita por mim e a pessoa abre a mesma, as fórmulas não funcionam e a fórmula fica assim " ='H:\GESTAO\Manuela Folly\Addin\Fundos.xla'!consultaValorPL($N$1;A424) "

Comment: Não sei se entendi: na hora de encaminhar ele acrescenta na fórmula o caminho do arquivo, eh isso? Se for, basta no original tu já colocar o nome do arquivo.xla e encaminhar ele junto. Assim: "='Fundos.xla'!consultaValorPL($N$1;A424)"

Comment: O nome do suplemento é o mesmo do que algum outro Sub ou Function já existente? Procure por duplicatas e certifique que o arquivo Excel está habilitado para macros.

Comment: Exatamente @Szag-Ot, se eu renomear a fórmula do jeito que vc falou ela funciona, mas o que eu não queria era dar esse retrabalho para a pessoa que recebe a planilha, pois ela só iria fazer uma pequena validação.

Comment: Mas vc não vai dar trabalho pra quem recebe se no seu arquivo vc fizer essa alteração. Basta alterar e depois mandar ambos os arquivos pra pessoa que deverá salvar ambos na mesma pasta. Só isso